# Prove that 2 cyclic subgroups of same order are either equal or contain $e$ only as intersection?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

Can someone give me a proof that $2$ cyclic subgroups of same order in a group are either equal or their intersection is $e$.  I think Lagrange's theorem is required for it.  Also suggest some visual interpretation of this proof.

Answer (score 5):

It is not true.

Consider the Quaternion group $Q_8$.
It contains two cyclic groups of same order which are
$$\langle i \rangle=\{1,i,-1,-i\}$$
and $$\langle j \rangle=\{1,j,-1,-j\}$$
Obviously, they are not equal and also their intersection which is $\{1,-1\}$ is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If the order of each of the cyclic groups is the same prime number $p$, then it is true. And yes you can use Lagrange’s Theorem to prove this.

Comment: will you please write the proof for me?

Comment: If $H$ and $K$ are two _distinct_ subgroups of both order $p$ a prime (this implies that these subgroups must be cyclic by the way; observe in addition that all non-trivial elements of $H$ and $K$ have order $p$), then consider the subgroup $H \cap K$. Assume $H \cap K$ contains an element $g \neq 1$, then since the order of $g$ is $p$, we obtain $H=\langle g \rangle = K$, a contradiction.

Comment: Different proof: $| H \cap K|$ divides $|H|$. So $|H \cap K|=1$ or $|H \cap K|=p$. In the latter case $H \cap K=H$, whence $H \subseteq K$, and since $|H|=|K|$, this yields $H=K$, a contradiction.